# How to mass delete rows in database table that are NOT in array using Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, fluent

I'd like to delete the rows in my table which are not in the array. In the following example, this will mass delete rows that correspond to $cards_to_delete.

```
$cards_to_delete = array(1, 2, 3);
Collection::where('username', '=', $username)
    ->whereIn('id', $cards_to_delete)
    ->delete();
```

How can I make it so it deletes everything that is NOT in the array? Something along these lines:

```
$cards_to_keep = array(1, 2, 3);
Collection::where('username', '=', $username)
    ->whereIn('id', '!=', $cards_to_keep)
    ->delete();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel provides a `->whereNotIn()` method as well:

```
$cards_to_keep = array(1, 2, 3);
Collection::where('username', '=', $username)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $cards_to_keep)
    ->delete();
```